# Parsing a single tree for a sequence using NLTK in Python

Tags: python, parsing, tree, nltk

I want to parse  a tree for an RNA sequence. I tokenized the RNA sequence in a list as is shown in the code below and parsed the trees:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import nltk
import pdb
import numpy as np
import h5py
import RNA_vae
import equation_vae_copy
import RNA_grammar

sent = ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'U', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'U', 'U', 'A']
parser = nltk.ChartParser(RNA_grammar.GCFG) 
parse_trees = [next(parser.parse(t)) for t in sent]

print(parse_trees)
```

But the output of the code is as below:

```
[Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['C'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['C'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['C'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['C'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['A'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['A'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['A'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['U'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['A'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['C'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['A'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['G'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['A'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['A'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['G'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['C'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['G'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['G'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['G'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['C'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['U'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['U'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('L', ['A'])])]
```

I want to make a tree for the whole of the sequence, but it makes the trees for each of the characters in RNA. How can I generate a single tree for whole of the sequence?

The grammar is as below:

```
# the RNA grammar
gram = """S -> LS
S -> L
LS -> L
LS -> S
L -> AFU
L -> UFA
L -> GFC
L -> CFG
L -> 'A'
L -> 'U'
L -> 'C'
L -> 'G'
F -> AFU
F -> UFA
F -> GFC
F -> CFG
F -> LS
AFU -> 'A'
AFU -> F
AFU -> 'U'
UFA -> 'U'
UFA -> F
UFA -> 'A'
GFC -> 'G'
GFC -> F
GFC -> 'C'
CFG -> 'C'
CFG -> F
CFG -> 'G'
Nothing -> Nones
"""
```

The grammar must be as below:

[image: RNA grammar]

Then, I changed the grammar as follows, but it still fails to parse a sequence:

```
gram = """S -> L S | L
L -> 'A' F 'U' | 'A' | 'U' F 'A' | 'U' | 'C' F 'G' | 'C' | 'G' F 'C' | 'G'
F -> 'A' F 'U' | 'U' F 'A' | 'C' F 'G' | 'G' F 'C' | L S
Nothing -> Nones
"""
```

Comment: If you want to parse the whole string, you need to call `parser.parse(sent)`. If you give the parser just one thing, that's what it parses. But why are you using a *natural language* toolkit to parse DNA sequences?

Comment: I tried ```parser.parse(sent)```, but when I try to print it, it shows nothing. It seems that the parsing has not done. I have defined the grammar for RNA.

Comment: That probably means that the parse failed, not that it didn't happen. But you don't show your grammar, so I don't know.

Comment: I added the grammar

Comment: Without looking too closely at that grammar, it's evident that it can only match a single character, because not one of the productions has more than one thing on the right. So it's probably not correct. I suppose it was an erroneous attempt to convert the grammar you were given into Chomsky Normal Form in order to be able to chart parse it. Let me ask you again: why are you using a chart parser for something like this? Are you required to use it or was it just the first parsing framework you stumbled onto? If the second, you might want to try a different one.

Comment: Thank you so much. Instead of writing two things at the right side, I splitted them and wrote them in different lines. I want to parse the RNA sequence and then by indexing each rule, I want to make one-hot vectors of the rules and finally, convert the input data to a matrix of one-hot vectors. Which parsing method do you recommend?

Comment: That's not the way grammars work. If you write `LS -> L` and `LS -> S`, you are saying that `LS` could be `L` or `S`, not that it is one followed by the other. To say that it's an `L` followed by an `S`, you need `LS -> L S`. So your first step is to write your grammar correctly.

Comment: After that, I don't know. I don't know a lot about bioinformatics, and you haven't said where you got the idea to use NLTK's chartparser. Certainly, the grammar you included as an image is not going to be easy to parse with a deterministic parser. If you really need a stochastic parser, NLTK might be an option. If you just want a list of possible parses for an ambiguous grammar, you could look at Lark (or other Python GLR/Earley parsers.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I fixed the grammar, but it still does not work. I got the idea of NLTK's chartparser from a paper which implemented it on molecules data with a different grammar.

Comment: "It didn't work" is a lament, not a problem description. If you're singing the blues, it's fine. If you're seeking assistance, you need to accurately **show** what you did, **specify** what you expected, **show** the actual result, and **explain** why it didn't meet your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, you started with two fundamental problems:

1. The grammar you wrote was only capable of handling a single character
2. You called your parser with one character each time.

The result was a vector of "parses" of each character, separately.

After fixing your grammar, as indicated in the editted question, changing the call to `parser.parse` to provide the entire sequence to be parsed produces 2100 possible parses.

Here's what I did (and you can do it, too, by just copying the following code block into your python console):

```py
# import only what's needed
import nltk
# The grammar
grammar = """
S -> L S | L
L -> 'A' F 'U' | 'A' | 'U' F 'A' | 'U' | 'C' F 'G' | 'C' | 'G' F 'C' | 'G'
F -> 'A' F 'U' | 'U' F 'A' | 'C' F 'G' | 'G' F 'C' | L S
"""
# Make a chartparser
parser = nltk.ChartParser(nltk.CFG.fromstring(grammar))
# The test sentence
sent = ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A',
        'U', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'A',
        'G', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'U',
        'U', 'A'
       ]
# Get all of the parses
parses = list(parser.parse(sent))
# There are a lot of them. len(parses) is 2100.
# Print one of them to the console
parses[0].pprint()
```

That prints:

```
(S
  (L C)
  (S
    (L C)
    (S
      (L C)
      (S
        (L C)
        (S
          (L A)
          (S
            (L A)
            (S
              (L A)
              (S
                (L
                  U
                  (F
                    (L A)
                    (S
                      (L C)
                      (S
                        (L A)
                        (S
                          (L G)
                          (S
                            (L
                              A
                              (F
                                A
                                (F G (F C (F (L G) (S (L G))) G) C)
                                U)
                              U))))))
                  A)))))))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How can I force it to compute only parses[0] instead of generating a long list of parses and then choosing parses[0]?

Comment: @narcis: NLTK's ChartParser returns a generator, not a list. I used the `list` builtin to produce a list by forcing the generator. If you just want the first parse, use `next`. But there's no reason to believe that the first parse is the "best", whatever that might mean, and I don't believe it's a uniformly random selection from the set of possibilities either.

Comment: NLTK is a big complicated package. It's reasonably well-documented in the NLTK book, which is not paywalled afaik, but which is a book. If you're going to rely on NLTK, you should probably spend a bit of time reading it.

Comment: Thank you so much. ```next``` works only in Python 2.7. Is there any substitution for that for Python 3.7?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next

Comment: Works fine for me on that very example.